# How to format outputs as a table in Java?

Tags: java, gpa

I'm trying to make a table out for a grade report, which should 5 columns, which are Class, Description, Units, Grade, and Grade Points.
However, I cannot make the output aligned with each other.
I'm just simply using "\t".
Is there a way to make the outputs as a table in Java?

```
import java.util.*;
public class Project1_Trial2 {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Input the term
        System.out.println("Please enter the term of your grade calculation (for example, Fall 2015): ");
        String term = scanner.nextLine();

        //Input the number of courses that the student is enrolled in
        System.out.println("Please enter the number of courses that you are enrolled in "+term+": ");
        int numberofcourses = scanner.nextInt();

        //Declaration
        String ClassName[] = new String[numberofcourses];
        String Description[] = new String[numberofcourses];
        String Grade[] = new String[numberofcourses];
        int Units[] = new int[numberofcourses];

        //Arrays for class number, description, units, grade, grades point
        //Here, input class number, description, units, and grades
        for(int i = 0; i < numberofcourses; i++)
        {
            scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Please enter your #"+(i+1)+" class name: ");
            ClassName[i] = scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Please enter your #"+(i+1)+" class description: ");
            Description[i] = scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Please enter your #"+(i+1)+" class units: ");
            Units [i] = scanner.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Please enter your #"+(i+1)+" class grade: ");
            Grade[i] = scanner.nextLine();
        }

        System.out.println("Class Grades - "+term+" Term");
        System.out.println("Office Grades");
        System.out.println("Class \t \t Description \t \t Units \t \t Grade \t \t Grade Points");
        for(int i = 0; i < numberofcourses; i++)
        {
        System.out.println(ClassName[i]+"\t \t"+Description[i]+"\t \t"+Units[i]+"\t \t"+Grade[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15193812/how-to-print-a-table-of-arrays/15194265#15194265) and [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22599302/properly-aligning-strings-on-the-console/22599518#22599518)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various ways to align your output so they align evenly....one way is to replace where you put:

```
System.out.println(ClassName[i]+"\t \t"+Description[i]+"\t \t"+Units[i]+"\t \t"+Grade[i]);
```

with:

```
System.out.printf("%-15s %-15s %-15s ",ClassName[i],Description[i],String.format("%5d", Units[i]),Grade[i]);
```

instead of using `System.out.println()` use `System.out.printf()` that way you can pad the strings and use `String.format()` inside the `printf()` function to pad the integer with spaces...you can adjust my padding to whatever you feel fit
this is a more efficient way rather than constantly using tabs